# Calling gradle script build.gradle with a setting whether it should build debug/release flavour and write generic tasks?

Tags: gradle, ant, msbuild, build.gradle

Ciao ragazzi,

I'm coming from ant and I'm trying to solve a very simple task in gradle:

I would like to call build.gradle in a way that sets the desired build flavour (Debug/Release) and all the rest of the tasks I would like to develop in a very generic way without duplication for Debug/Release.

In the old world with ant I simply wrote a target, which depended on one target setting the relevant (generic) properties and another target, which used those properties and triggered the build.

In gradle it seems I didn't entirely understand the configuration phase. So this is the current state of development:

```
plugins {
  id "com.ullink.msbuild" version "2.15"
  id "com.ullink.nuget" version "2.12"
  // id "java"
}

task config(type: configurationTask)

class configurationTask extends DefaultTask {
    private BuildType buildType = BuildType.Debug;
    private Date date = new Date();

    @Option(option = "buildType", description = "Configures the build flavour.")
    public void setBuildType(BuildType buildType) {
        this.buildType = buildType;
    }

    public String getBuildType() {
        return buildType;
    }

    public String getMsBuildName() {
        return 'CMS_' + date.format('yyyyMMdd_HHmmss') + '_' + buildType;
    }

    @TaskAction
    def showConfiguration() {
        println('The build configuration is:')
        println('BuildType: ' + buildType)
        println('BuildName: ' + getMsBuildName())
    }

    private static enum BuildType {
        Debug, Release
    }
}

version = "4.41.0.0"
def buildTimestamp = getTimestamp()

def _buildType = config.getBuildType()
def _msBuildName = config.getMsBuildName()

println("Project    : $project")
println("Name       : $name")
println("Path       : $path")
println("Description: $description")
println("ProjectDir : $projectDir")
println("BuildDir   : $buildDir")
println("Group      : $group")
println("Version    : $version")
println("Ant        : $ant")

msbuild {
      //verbosity = 'detailed'
      //verbosity = 'diag'

      // targets to execute (/t:Clean;Rebuild, no default)
      // targets = ['Clean', 'Rebuild']
      //parameters.platform = 'Any CPU'
}

task buildSolution(type: msbuild.class) {
    description = 'Builds the solution in the chosen flavour.'

    dependsOn 'config'

    println("123: ${_buildType}")
    println("321: ${_msBuildName}")

    solutionFile = 'CMS.sln'
    configuration = "${_buildType}"
    parameters.OutDir = "${buildDir}/${_msBuildName}"

    // you can also provide properties by name (/p:SomeProperty=Value)
    parameters.GenerateProjectSpecificOutputFolder=true
    parameters.OutDirWasSpecified=true 

    // Generates XML documentation file (from javadoc through custom DocLet)
    generateDoc = false

    println("Configuration for '${configuration}': ${parameters}")
    println("parameters.OutDir: ${parameters.OutDir}")
}

def getTimestamp() {
    def date = new Date()
    return date.format('yyyyMMdd_HHmm')
}
```

My idea was that this could be called somehow like `gradle config --buildType Release buildSolution` in order to build the release flavour.

Unfortunately the configurationTask itself is setting and printing everything correctly, but the build task is still building only the Debug flavour.

Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong or better how to do it right?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Tanti saluti

Florian

Answer (score 0):

The code above can't work. You're reading the values at configuration time but only setting them at execution time. Generally you don't configure tasks from other tasks. You simply create a task for everything you need.

In the simplest case this would just be a for-loop over the values of your buildType enum, creating one task for each. If you want to do less hard-coding, you could also use the `Project.container` method to create an extensible container of buildTypes so your users could define their own.

Also have a look at Gradle's own [native plugins](https://github.com/gradle/gradle-native), which currently handle C++ and Swift.

Comment: Thanks a lot Stefan! I’ll figure it out and post my final solution.

Comment: Hi Stefan, could you please give me a clue how to use the android plugin without having to install the whole tool chain of Android given that my project is a regular C# project? Is there an alternative plugin I could use? Thanks a lot in advance. Best regards. Florian

Comment: I'm sorry, I wrongly assumed that you have an Android project and you are just trying to add some native code on top of it, because the Android plugin has the exact some naming of "buildType". I'll adjust my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ciao ragazzi,

I figured out a solution, which works for me and I want to share it with you:

```
plugins {
  id "com.ullink.msbuild" version "2.15"
  id "com.ullink.nuget" version "2.12"
  // id "java"
}

println("Project    : $project")
println("Name       : $name")
println("Path       : $path")
println("Description: $description")
println("ProjectDir : $projectDir")
println("BuildDir   : $buildDir")
println("Group      : $group")
println("Version    : $version")
println("Ant        : $ant")

def buildTimestamp = getTimestamp()
def buildNamePrefix = "ABC"
def buildTypes = ['Debug', 'Release']

buildTypes.each { variant -> 
    task "Build${variant}"(type: msbuild.class) {
        description = "Builds the solution in '${variant}' flavour."

        solutionFile = 'ABC.sln'
        configuration = "${variant}"
        parameters.OutDir = "${buildDir}\\${buildNamePrefix}_${buildTimestamp}_${variant}"

        // you can also provide properties by name (/p:SomeProperty=Value)
        parameters.GenerateProjectSpecificOutputFolder=true
        parameters.OutDirWasSpecified=true 

        // Generates XML documentation file (from javadoc through custom DocLet)
        generateDoc = false

        doFirst {
            println("Building '${configuration}' flavour ...")
            println("${parameters}")
            println()
        }
        doLast {
            println()
            println("Finished '${configuration}' build.")
        }
    } 
}

buildTypes.each { variant -> 
    task "ZipBuild${variant}"(type: Zip) {
        description = "Builds the solution in '${variant}' flavour and creates a zip file."
        dependsOn "Build${variant}"

        archiveName = "${buildNamePrefix}_${buildTimestamp}_${variant}.zip"
        destinationDir = file("${buildDir}")
        from("${buildDir}/${buildNamePrefix}_${buildTimestamp}_${variant}") {
            include "ABC*/"
            exclude "ABCAdminClasses/"
        }

        doFirst {
            println("Creating '${destinationDir}\\${archiveName}' ...")
        }
        doLast {
            println("Finished writing '${destinationDir}\\${archiveName}'.")
        }
    } 
}

def getTimestamp() {
    def date = new Date()
    return date.format('yyyyMMdd_HHmm')
}
```

Running `gradle tasks --all` shows the new tasks.

Best regards,

Florian